# PDO query is returning each field twice in the result set

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have the strangest issue that I can't resolve. I have a simple MySQL query that returns each field in results twice. The first with the key named the field name and the second an integer.

The table looks like this:

```
id int(11)
user_id int(11)
first_name varchar(255)
last_name varchar(255)
country_code varchar(3)
mobile varchar(255)
email varchar(255)
profile_img var_char(255)
timestamp timestamp
```

My code looks like this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=proj', 'dev', '<password>');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contact";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$contacts = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($contacts));
```

And the output is:

```
Array
(  
[id] => 1  
[0] => 1  
[user_id] => 1  
[1] => 1  
[first_name] => joan  
[2] => joan  
[last_name] => smith  
[3] => smith  
[country_code] => AU  
[4] => AU  
[mobile] => 0400 222 333  
[5] => 0400 222 333  
[email] => joan@example.com  
[6] => joan@example.com  
[profile_img] =>   
[7] =>  
[timestamp] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00  
[8] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00  
)
```

I am using MariaDB 15.1 and PHP 7.0 in a Debian 9.1 VM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you didn't set the `mode` (formerly known as `fetch_style`) parameter of `$stmt->fetchAll();`. By default, PDO fetches the results as an array with both numbered and associative keys (*e.g.*, "first_name" and 2).

From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

> **mode**
>
> Controls the contents of the returned array as documented in `PDOStatement::fetch()`. Defaults to value of `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` (which defaults to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`)

To get only the associative indexes, pass the parameter `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, as in

```
$contacts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

To get only the numbered indexes, pass the parameter `PDO::FETCH_NUM`, as in

```
$contacts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

The full set of options is listed in [the documentation for `PDOStatement::fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.